# Assume $E\subset\mathbb{R}^p, F\subset\mathbb{R}^q$, does $E,F$ has to be measurable so that $E\times F$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume $E\subset\mathbb{R}^p, F\subset\mathbb{R}^q$ and $E\times F$ is measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$.

Is it possible for any of $E,F$ is not measurable in their own space?

Comment: Well, the empty set is measurable, so even if $F$ is not measurable, the product $\emptyset \times F = \emptyset$ is still measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, we are trying to figure out whether every projection of a measurable set is measurable. Consider the interval $[0,1]$, there is a set $E$ that is not measurable in $[0,1]$. Now consider $E\times\{0\}$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$, this set is a null set, hence measurable. Here, I am assuming we are working with the Lebesgue measure on the Lebesgue algebra (so, every null set is measurable).

Comment: Does null set means measure is $0$??

Comment: Notice that $E \times\{0\}\subset [0,1]\times\{0\}$, which is just a strip and has measure $0$. Yes, a null set is a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Null sets are not necessarily measurable. This depends on the context. You could be working with only Borelsets being measurable.

Comment: From lebesgue-measure tag, your assumption of working with the Lebesue algebra is certainly appropriate.